# delete file image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

My intention is to delete file from folder But Here in above script is not working properly can any one please suggest me about this

```
function deleteFile()
{
    var myObject;
    myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    myObject.DeleteFile("D:\\WEBSITE_FILES\\docs\\OTR\\"+db_unicid+"\\passportImage.jpg");
    return true;
}


 <input type='Button' value='Click to Delete File' onClick='return deleteFile()'>
```

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome the above script in javascript is not working any one can plz check the code

Comment: @Sony ... ActiveXObject is an Internet Exploder only abomination that even Microsoft abandoned

Comment: Ok can you please provide necessary script in javascript in google chrome

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete files with Javascript. It mostly has to do with security issues. Also, right now ActiveX Object is only supported by IE, so you'll have troubles with it in every other browser. You should do it just with PHP or with an Ajax call to a PHP file.

the PHP (this would be a file called deleteFile.php)

```
<?php 
   unlink($_GET['file']);
?>
```

and the JavaScript

```
function deleteFile()
{
    $.ajax({
      url: 'deleteFile.php',
      data: {'file' : "<?php echo dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploads/'?>" + file_name },
      success: function (response) {
         // do something
      },
      error: function () {
         // do something
      }
    });
}

<input type='Button' value='Click to Delete File' onClick='return deleteFile()'>
```

Comment: i am using jsp..can i write code in php and where i need to add this path in above code  Path =D:\\WEBSITE_FILES\\docs\\OTR\\"+db_unicid+"\\passportImage.jpg");

Comment: you just need to make the ajax call in JSP instead of jQuery and it would work. sorry, I'm not very good with JSP.